# Alternative to materialized view

Tags: oracle11g, materialized-views

I have a UI which needs to be populated by an underlying database query. This query is quite complicated having several joins between tables and take around 2-3 minute to execute. I tried using materialized view but I want the most recent data ( as base tables are very frequently updated) and materialized view "on commit refresh" will make update/insert on base tables slow which I can not afford. Is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use fast refresh and schedule the mview refresh on frequent interval